# .Net Core Slow after idle

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7.5

I have a new .netcore web app deployed to a windows server 2008R2 IIS instance, and after the app has been idle for a while, it's slow upon first load, and then subsequent requests are super fast.

In previous versions of .net I changed the Idle Time-out property of the app pool in IIS to 0 to fix this issue. Is there a similar setting somewhere with .netcore, perhaps something I've missed I could add to the Startup.cs file?

Comment: ASP.NET Core per see has no lifetime recycling. It's the IIS which does it, so you need to set up it up there, as IIS is responsible for starting and stopping the (ASP).NET Core application

Comment: @Tseng What would you suggest? I have IIS set the never time out, yet the .netcore app still takes longer to spool up for the very first time after it's been idle for a while. I took wolvenhaven's advice in his answer whipped up a quick script which just hit's one of the pages in the app and that seems to be helping.

Comment: If you can reproduce this consistently, can you file a bug https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baring there being a legitimate fix as I am unfamiliar with .netcore; writing a route which returns an HTTP 200 or something as a heartbeat and then calling it from a scheduled task every X minutes(idle - 1) would prevent the application from ever idling and thus keep it from slowing down requests.

Answer (score 2):

How about setting up the Application Pool Idle time on IIS?

[image: Advanced Settings - Application Pool]

Also make sure the recycling settings are unchecked

[image: Edit Application pool Recycling Settings]

Comment: Did you read my question? This was the first thing I attempted.

Comment: Yes I did, and surprisingly it is working after using ASP.NET Core v1.0.1

Comment: That's odd.. I changed the same setting on .net core 1.0.1 and it didn't change a thing.

Comment: Have you checked the progress in task manager? I know from past that the kestrel app disappeared in task manager after a while...

Comment: I did, and the kestrel .net core app is always around the top of the active processes. Although that could be because the idle service I wrote is pinging the site every minute.